# Defining Interface inside activity

Tags: android, interface, android-activity

In my android application inside activity I am defining one interface like this :

```
 public interface sideFilterInterface
    {
        public void changeFilters(int layoutId);
    }
```

inside activity I use this interface like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCallback = (sideFilterInterface) this;
    mCallback.changeFilters(R.layout.filter_details);
}
```

I am implementing this interface in another fragment. when i tried this code it gives me error regarding casting here `mCallback = (sideFilterInterface) this;`

How to do this. Am I doing something wrong. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: are you implementing the interface ?? activity implements Interface1

Comment: you want fragment to communicate with activity?

Comment: @Atrix i am not implementing interface for my activity. Is it needed ?

Comment: if you want fragment to communicate with activity as @Raghunandan asked then you have to implement your interface in activity

Comment: if you don't implement an interface then how will a particular class be of that type and will cause a ClassCastException, i.e. if A and B don't belong to the same hierarchy then you cannot cast it, simple java, i guess you are new to the language, just go through the basics

Comment: @Raghunandan no i don't want to fragment to communicate with activity. It's just event to trigger something inside another fragment. Thank you for replay.

Comment: Is that fragment's parent activity is the activity that you specify in your question?

Comment: @Atrix1987 I'm facing similar problem, I want to send data activity to navigation drawer fragment but my activity seperate from fragment. I'm defining interface but it give me error :S  Can not cast to activity says.

Comment: @salih post your question with ur code and tag me in the comment, i'll reply.. not sure what you are doing

Comment: Actually my question is simple. Is it possible to cast interface in activity. for interfragment communication ı used this code  ""communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();"" but when i use this in activity like this ""communicator = (Communicator) this;"". It gives me error can not cast interface to activity. communicator is interface. Only my problems is here.

Comment: @Atrix1987 I've asked my question you can see here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006530/communication-between-activity-and-fragment/29007156#comment46261385_29007156

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you are trying to cast your Activity into Listener if you are not implementing the Listener in your activity.

If you are calling the `public void changeFilters(int layoutId)` through the interface , the code will not execute as the method in the interface is abstract.You need to implement the listener in the activity and then do the code there . Something like :

```
     public class YourActivity extends Activity implements sideFilterInterface{
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 //some code
                 this.changeFilters(R.layout.filter_details);
            }
            @Override
            public void changeFilters(int layoutId) {
                //Implement here
           }
   }
```