# Communication between Activity and Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello Everyone I'm developing an app,in order to explain my situation I've created simple illustrator. When i click the button inside another activity i want to send data to fragment. I use bundle its gives me nullpointerexception. I tried to use method inside another activity it gives me error again. How can i pass data from Activity to Fragment thanks in advance.

Here my codes.

**Edit1 :** I think i explained wrong. Look at photo that i've uploaded. When i click the white button anotheractivity is opening. When i typing some text inside anotheractivity and click the button inside anotheractivity, then i want to send datas Fragment class. I hope i was able to explained. Thanks.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AnotherActivity**

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {
    EditText et;
    Button btn;
    public String ets;
    FragmentClass myFragment = new FragmentClass();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anotheractivity);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ets = et.getText().toString();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myFragment.Test(ets);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false);
        tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        return v;
    }


    public void Test(String name){
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: To which activity is the Fragment attached to. In the image its attached to MainActivity

Comment: Yes, fragment is attached to mainactivity and i want to send data from anotheractivity to fragment. (not: mainactivity to fragment)

Comment: You can use `startActivityForResult` Override `onActivityResult`.

Comment: you can also use third party libraries like greenrobots eventbus

Comment: i am not able to understand your question. Do you want to communicate info between 2 activities and you want to use that in a fragment . Am I correct ?

Comment: When i click star inside mainactivity,  second activty opens. When i click listview  items inside second activity i want to send data from  second activity to fragment.

Comment: @raghunandan are you sure EventBus works for this use case?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it should but i haven't tried it

Comment: @raghunandan well in that case you would have to unsubscribe from the bus in onDestroy instead of onStop or onPause, i guess.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you can unsubscribe when the fragment gets detached from activity

Comment: Since I don't see the vote for Best Answer. Is this still a problem?

Comment: I've done this stuff using interfaces. Thank you. As I mentioned previous question, your network profile dont have any e-mail adress

Answer (score 2):

You can put different data inside Bundle (i passed an object and an string in following example), also use FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. Try something like this inside your onClick in AnotherActivity:

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("SomeObject", obj);
            bundle.putString("attribute", "some string value");
            otf.setArguments(bundle);

            fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.container, myFragment, "MYFRAGMENT_NAME");
            ft.addToBackStack("MYFRAGMENT_NAME");
            ft.commit();
```

Then inside new fragment you use `getArguments()` to get data from Bundle.

Comment: Thanks for comment but myfragment class is already added on the map. I dont need to add with fragment transaction. Am i wrong ?

Comment: I would recomend using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. Just calling fragment class is not correct way to do it according to official documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2):

**This is best practice to communicate between Activity and Fragment**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ATAG = "atag";

    public static TestFragment getFragment(int value){
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ATAG, 100);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container,false);
        Bundle  b = getArguments();
            if(b!= null)
                YOUR DATA = b.getInt(ATAG);
        return view;
    }
}
```

And the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String FOO = "foofragment";

    TestFragment newFragment;
    Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            newFragment = TestFragment.getFragment(100);    
        }else {
            newFragment = (TestFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FOO);
        }

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();     
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();   
            transaction.add(R.id.container, newFragment, FOO);          
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for comment. My fragment is already added to map but you recommend me to use fragment transaction. When i launch the app, fragment is coming properly.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers on this page all contain pieces of the answer that you can use after you fully understand how Activities and Fragments work, but it sounds to me as if you do not understand them yet.

There are many good resources, both books and websites, that you can learn from, but here's some basics that I suspect are tripping you up:

- Only one Activity is active at any given time.
- Activities have a 'lifecycle' - a series of states ranging from fully inactive to fully active, and standard methods that are called as each state is reached.
- A Fragment must be attached to an Activity.
- Fragments have activity lifecycles similar to (but not exactly the same as) Activities.
- You cannot safely invoke a method in one Activity from another Activity. If you want to pass data between two Activities, you usually do it through an Intent.
- You cannot communicate directly between an Activity or Fragment and another Activity or a Fragment in another activity. If, as it appears from your question, you want data from an Activity to be communicated to a Fragment in another Activity, you must pass the data to the other Activity in an Intent, and then have that Activity communicate it to it's Fragment at the proper point in the lifecycle.